# Deploying VueJS App into a folder with an executable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-deployment

I'm trying to find a way to deploy a VueJS Project out of VirtualStudio into a folder with an executable.
I'm probalby missing something but i think of a solution much like publishing a c# Razorpage project where afterwards i can start the Webapplication with an .exe file.

Is there any out of the box solution without needing something like Docker or thelike?

Comment: The output of Vue project is html file and associated assets (js, css, etc). It's up to you how they are used, they can be served with any web server of your choice, Docker or not. This is not specific to Vue.

Comment: For this certain case i ended up just copying the project files to the destination folder and than using a script in the windows Taskscheduler to navigate to the folder and start the App with an "npm run serve" command.